# getChildFragmentManager > beginTransaction > replace > commit: no result

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have main activity with only ViewPager on it. The first tab page fragment contains:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/llEventsTabPage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvEvents"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to show details fragment when user taps item in ListView:

```
lvEvents.setAdapter(adapter);
lvEvents.setOnItemClickListener(
            new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {                     
                    Fragment eventFragment = new EventFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.llEventsTabPage, eventFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        );
```

Code 'fragmentTransaction.commit();' is called, onCreateView of EventFragment is called, but after 'fragmentTransaction.commit();' nothing happens. No errors, no result. Just list view is still displaying and working.

What am I doing wrong? I've found a few examples, my code looks the same, but not working and I can do nothing with that.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the addtobackstack(null) until you make it work. Then you can add it (preferably after the commit();)

You seem to be replacing, but, was there a fragment before? do you need to construct a new instance of the Fragment on every click? why not reuse it? Too many questions :)

Please provide more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do a `replace` or `add`, all it's going to do is add the `Fragment`'s View to the container that you specify.  The only difference is this:

`replace` will remove the first existing Fragment inside the container previously `that is handled by the FragmentManager specified`.

`add` will simply add the Fragment to the container.

In your case, you have a LinearLayout container which holds a ListView that is of size `match_parent`.  What this means is, when the ChildFragmentManager adds your Fragment to the container, it will add it to a LinearLayout.  The fragment is actually below the ListView outside the scope of the View.

Change LinearLayout to FrameLayout and your Fragment will appear over the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not be sure. but I use two layout structures.

**first layout structure**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

in this case, you need two fragment.
one is a EventFragment and other one is a Fragment for ListView.
so you should additionally create fragment for ListView.

**second layout structure**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

in this case, you commit R.id.fragment_container instead R.id.llEventsTabPage.
I think it would operate....